# Bootstrap : breadcrumb remove slash?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, breadcrumbs

In Bootstrap 3 there is default slash(/) symbol between breadcrumb elements. How to remove it? And I am want to replace '/' with '>'.

Code snippet:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a><span>></span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a><span>></span></li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

The demo of my code [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mridulpv/hguAW/)

Comment: Try editing bootstrap.css or overriding the `breadcrumb` class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
    content: "\3E"
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hguAW/2/

Comment: how to remove the default background color?